# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to closure result type 'Void' in Swift

Tags: swift

Any suggestion why my code return error( I already provide details of the function I've made what cause that error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to closure result type 'Void'

```
let tes = fetchUser(completionHandler: { baseData, error in
    if let baseData = baseData {
        let parm_key : String = baseData["parm_key"] as! String
        return baseData
    }
})
print(tes)


func fetchUser(completionHandler: @escaping ([String:Any]?, Error?) -> [String:Any]) {
            ...  
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                
                guard let data = data else { return }
                let stringData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                let encryptedResult = stringData.data(using: .utf8)!
                
                if let data = Data(base64Encoded: encryptedResult) {
                    let firstDecoded = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                    let countDrop = Int(String(firstDecoded.prefix(2))) ?? 0
                    let base64EncodedData = firstDecoded.dropFirst(countDrop + 2)
                    if let secondData = Data(base64Encoded: String(base64EncodedData)) {
                        let secondDecoded = Data(String(data: secondData, encoding: .utf8)!.utf8)
                        do {
                            // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
                            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: secondDecoded, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                                completionHandler(json, nil)
                            }
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Show the context of the first bit of code. Is that inside some method that has a return value?

Comment: I've added the detail about my function

Comment: Sorry, that's not the details that are needed. You need to show where the line `let tes = fetchUser...` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion handler closure takes two arguments but does not return a value. You need to remove the `return` line and perhaps update another variable (in the scope outside the closure) with the needed value. The error means that the function is not expecting to return anything (void), yet a dictionary (baseData) is returned.

In your example, does `tes` have the value you need? How to handle this will depend on how `fetchUser()` is defined, but it probably doesn’t return the value directly. You must assign it to something in the completion handler.

```
var returnedBaseData = [String:Any]()

fetchUser(completionHandler: { baseData, error in
    if let baseData = baseData {
        returnedBaseData = baseData
    }
})
```

Comment: The declaration of `fetchUser` is shown in the question.

Comment: when I declared new variable like that, the `returnedBaseData` only return [:].
I think that because `fetchUser()` is asynchronous

Comment: @Andikatama That’s right. If you check it just after the call to `fetchUser` it will be empty as it is still waiting on the completionHandler. You could use the data in the completion handler.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes sorry, I had forgotten that while writing my answer.

Comment: so if I want to use `returnedBaseData`, I need to make the function as asynchronous right? to prevent return [:] when I trying to `print()`

Comment: @Andikatama Yes, that’s right. Completion handlers are fine if you can do what you need in the handler, but using Swift async / await is a newer and simpler way to achieve this that is much easier to work with.